# Selecting Specific Values From Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently working on a MySQL query that requires me to pull the language preference of specific consumers. However, the language preference is not built in as it's own column and neither is the named title "LanguagePreference" it's own column either. Instead it looks something like this:

```
**USRV_PROP_NAME      USRV_PROP_VALUE**
CurStreet             ABC Street
CurCity               ABC City
CurState              TX
ResdienceType         Rent
AppSource             ABC Source
LanguagePreference    Spanish
```

I know how to grab the "LanguagePreference". All I do is put USRV_PROP_VALUE as a column in the SELECTs and then specify USRV_PROP_NAME = 'LanguagePreference' as a conition. However, this only provides me with apps that have a specified 'LanguagePreference'. But not all apps have this specified and I want those apps to show up as well. I have also tried:

```
IF(USRV_PROP_NAME = 'LanguagePreference',USRV_PROP_VALUE,NULL)
```

But this brings all the values back as NULL. Is there anything I can do to try to get the results I am looking for?

Comment: what result you looking for ? can you edit and put desired result ?

Comment: Your `IF` condition looks fine to me. You might want to check the literal value mentioned in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition to:

```
USRV_PROP_NAME = 'LanguagePreference' OR USRV_PROP_NAME IS NULL
```

Comment: I think this did the trick. I thought it was something I had tried previously but realized I wasn't doing a left join to coincide.